# Prestashop query sell

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to execute a query after a sell of a product using the ps_product_attribute.reference of the selled product to insert that value in another custom table already created. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module with hook `actionObjectOrderAddAfter`. It receives the object Order as a parameter.

Then apply all the logic that you need.

Comment: ok i've read about that hook, but i'm a newbie of prestashop and a python programmer with php basic skills... if i create a new php file in my root what php file have to import to use that hook and execute a sql query?

Comment: @tascio You need to create a module. Use `PrestaShop Module Generator` (https://validator.prestashop.com/generator) to create a simple module. You just need to hook module in this position.

Comment: @tascio did you succeed?